# QuickFIX: Load a message from the logs

Tags: quickfix, fix-protocol

I am building a tool to replay logs. Manually parsing the logs is annoying, so I'm wondering if there is a way to simply load a message from the log.

Also, I am not against just using a third-party replay tool if one exists.

Comment: Which logs?  *.messages.current.log (or *.messages.log in older versions of QuickFIX)?  Or the ones from the FileStore?  Do you even use one or both of these optional parts of QuickFIX (they're available via your configuration file).

Comment: Whatever logs you tell me to use, I'm not picky and have access to all of them.

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by "replay"? Do you want a log-viewer that will let you look at the messages for a session in a nice format, or an application that can parse and then fire the historic messages into another FIX session?

Comment: I wanted "application that can parse and then fire the historic messages into another FIX session".

Comment: Since the original question could have been interpreted differently (now clarified in the comment) I've found [hffix](https://github.com/jamesdbrock/hffix) to be a very useful command line tool for replaying FIX logs in human readable format.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First read the log file by any mean you want, getting the individual lines (there is one message per line).

Then build a Data Dictionary:

```
// Use the version of the XML dictionary that is right for you
FIX::DataDictionary dd("FIX44.XML");
```

Then, for each line (as `std::string str`), build a message:

```
FIX::Message msg(str, dd, false);
```

Finally, handle the message just like your FIX::Application does, or better, call

```
yourFixApplication.fromApp(msg, mySessionID);
```

Comment: You may or may not want to also update any timestamp fields in the messages.

Comment: How would you parse the resulting message? I am looking for `quickfix` documentation of the `Message` class and cannot seem to find anywhere -- the general doc does not seem to reference it...

Answer (score 3):

ValidFIX Log analyzer is an online log parser that makes a good job:
http://www.validfix.com/fix-log-analyzer.html

Comment: That used to be free but now its commercial. It's a great tool, effective, quick, web based. But now it's expensive for an individual. But for a company it seems great because it has unlimited uses and unlimited users.

Comment: If the need is to quickly display FIX in a human readable format, try the FIX parser at http://fixparser.targetcompid.com

Comment: as well as https://fixparser.targetcompid.com there is also https://fixparser.chronicle.software